# ssrs expression with multiple html font properties

Tags: reporting-services

I'm adding an expression on VS 2017 above my report to display the name and some fields but also to display a second row with a different color and size. The font color works perfectly but for a reason the font size is the same on both rows (even when I put different size). Below is my code

```
    ="<font color='#4169e1' size='14pt'>" & "Platform by Account # " & Parameters!AccountID.Value & " " & "</font>" & "<br>" & 
"<font color='red' size='2pt'>" & "Report generated on: " & Now() & "</br> </font>"
```

Any suggestion to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the 'pt'

```
="<font color='#4169e1' size='14'>" & "Platform by Account # " & Parameters!AccountID.Value & " " & "</font>" & "<br>" & 
"<font color='red' size='2'>" & "Report generated on: " & Now() & "</br> </font>"
```

Comment: Thank you JonTout